# Display an Error message when signal is less than a value in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to display an Error message when the signal reaches a certain value or simply when it reaches 0 I've used the `if`block and `Relational Operator`but it does not work for me.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely checking if the signal is *exactly* zero, which with floating point arithmetic is almost always a very bad thing to do.

Rather, you want to check that the *absolute value* of the signal is less than some small tolerance.  More than that, you almost certainly need to check if the average of the signal over the past n-time points (where you choose n) is less than the tolerance.

You might also consider using something like the `Static Gap` block from the `Model Verification` library.

Comment: I've tried the `Static Gap`block but it does not work, I've setup the *Upper Bound to 0.1* and the *Lower Bound to 0* but does not work.

Comment: What are you feeding in to the `Static Gap` block?  If it's your signal then that almost certainly won't work because a signal value of -(a very small number) is outside your range.  As per my answer, make sure you are passing in its absolute value, and that you are passing in an average over a few time steps, not the value at just one time step, which will give spurious results.